# Good tools for collaborative review and approval?

Tags: web-apps, audio, collaboration

We're trying to launch a podcast series. We have a 5-person team and at least a dozen interviews in the can. We're finding it difficult to keep track of versioning and edit suggestions because we communicate solely through email+file server.

I've seen good online collaboration tools for video, stills, graphic design, and computer programming ([wipster](http://wipster.io), [frame](https://frame.io), [marqueed](http://www.marqueed.com), [jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira), [asana](https://asana.com), Google Docs, etc.).

Are there any online collaboration tools which are more specifically tailored to audio? Ideally, I'd like something which supported production transcripts.

Answer (score 1):

It's not specifically for audio but I'd always recommend Trello for project management - It's free, simple and it's got tons of integrations with 3rd party services.

You can get set up on it really fast and you can tailor your boards to your own workflow. https://trello.com

You can see examples of people use trello here: https://trello.com/b/fDsPBXFt/board-of-templates

Comment: Thanks.  Of course, I've seen that too.  There are plenty of lists of collaboration software out there (here's one: http://www.creativebloq.com/design/online-collaboration-tools-912855).  I'm interested in audio-centric collaboration.  The closest thing I've found so far is screenlight.com , and it's not exactly audio-centric, but it will at least work with audio, and generate waveform previews.

Comment: You could try using Indaba Music for collaboration, I used it once or twice in the past and it was a good experience. I think Ohmforce also have an online DAW you can use in near-realtime, but I'm not sure if that is still going.